# If a call to an attribute (eg a function) is sent from the component but the component If it has been unmounted, what is the common error message?

Tags: reactjs

If a call to an attribute (eg a function) is sent from the component but the component
If it has been unmounted, what is the common error message?
a. Crash app now
b. Memory leak
c. Window alert box
d. Nothing because React is smart to know the component is unmounted

Comment: Is this a homework question? You could always just try it and see.

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to do it

Comment: If you know, can you give me the answer and I will try to find out more

Answer (score 0):

It should be *"Can't perform a React state update on an unmonted component"*

[image: React unmonted error]

Comment: Which answer should I choose?

Comment: You can see the "Memory leak" mention in the error message

Comment: I'm ready here to ask for your help with this answer, I'm a newbie, have researched but still can't find the answer

Comment: useReducer on React Hooks and reducer on React Class
a. Have the same function and application place
b. Has different function and application place
c. Have different function but same application place
d. Have the same function but different application place